How to set and override the Woocommerce checkout field values with the values in select option
I design my own WooCommerce checkout. I put a select item at the top of page and the customers should select one of their predefined information or register for new info.
my code is as follow:
<?php
    $my_user = wp_get_current_user();
?>
<div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 20px; border: solid red 2px; border-radius: 10px; padding: 20px; margin-left: 10px; color: white;">
    <label style="color: red;"> Please select one of these addresses </label>
    <select name="address" id="address" onchange="change_address(this)" style="margin-top: 20px; width: 100%; height: 90%; font-family: B Roya; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">
        <option value="None"> Choosee --- </option>
        <option value="address_1">Address1: <?php echo $my_user-> user_address1; ?></option>
        <option value="address_2">Adress2: <?php echo $my_user-> user_address2; ?></option>
        <option value="address_new">New Address</option>
    </select>
</div>

<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php if ( $checkout->get_checkout_fields() ) : ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' );?> 

        <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details" style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 200px;">
            <div class="col-1" style="box-shadow: 12px 12px 12px #555; border: solid 2px red; width: 45%; flex: 3; padding: 20px; border-radius: 15px;">
                <p style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: red;"> Your Address </p>
                <table style="border: none;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="billing_first_name" style = "display: block; text-align: right;"> Full name* </label>
                        <input type="text" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" value="" style="text-align: right; width:100%; height:30px;" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('این بخش نمی تواند خالی باشد')">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="billing_phone" style = "display: block; text-align: right;"> Mobile* </label>
                        <input type="text" name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" value="" style="text-align: left; width:100%; height:30px;" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('این بخش نمی تواند خالی باشد')">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="billing_state" style="display: block; text-align: right;"> State* </label>
                        <input type="text" name="billing_state" id="billing_state" value="" style="text-align: right; width:100%; height:30px;" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('این بخش نمی تواند خالی باشد')">
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="billing_city" style="display: block; text-align: right;"> City* </label>
                        <input type="text" name="billing_city" id="billing_city" value="" style="text-align: right; width:100%; height:30px;" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('این بخش نمی تواند خالی باشد')">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"; style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="billing_address_1" style = "display: block; text-align: right;"> Address* </label>
                        <input type="text" name="billing_address_1" id="billing_address_1" value="" style="text-align: right; width:100%; height:30px;" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('این بخش نمی تواند خالی باشد')">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="billing_postcode" style="display: block; text-align: right;"> Postal code* </label>
                        <input type="text" name="billing_postcode" id="billing_postcode" value=""  style="text-align: left; width:100%; height:30px;" required>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 50%; padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="billing_email" style="display: block; text-align: right;"> email </label>
                        <input type="text" name="billing_email" id="billing_email" value=""  style="text-align:left; width:100%; height:30px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"; style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                        <label for="order_comments" style="display: block; text-align: right;"> Comments </label>
                        <textarea style="resize:none; text-align: right; width: 100%; height: 150px;" name="order_comments" id="order_comments" placeholder="در صورت نیاز، توضیحات تکمیلی در خصوص ارسال کالا را ثبت فرمایید "></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="col-2" style="box-shadow: 12px 12px 12px #555; border: solid 2px blue; width: 45%; flex: 3; padding: 20px; border-radius: 15px;">

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading' ); ?>
                
                <h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
                
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

                <div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
                </div>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php 
            do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); 
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', $checkout ); ?>
<?php //var_dump($checkout->get_checkout_fields()); ?>;

Here is my script for changing the information:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_address() 
    {   //print('Hello');
        //Reference the Button.
        var sel = document.getElementById("address");
        var name = document.getElementById("billing_first_name");
        var famil = document.getElementById("billing_last_name");
        var phone = document.getElementById("billing_phone");
        var state = document.getElementById("billing_state");
        var city = document.getElementById("billing_city");
        var address = document.getElementById("billing_address_1");
        var postcode = document.getElementById("billing_postcode");
        var email = document.getElementById("billing_email");
        var comment = document.getElementById("order_comments");
        
        var fname = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->account_first_name) ?>;
        var lname = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->account_last_name) ?>;
        if (sel.value.trim() == "address_1") {
            name.value = fname;//.concat(" ").concat(lname);
            phone.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_phone1); ?>;
            state.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_state1); ?>;
            city.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_city1); ?>;
            address.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_address1); ?>;
            postcode.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_postcode1); ?>;
            email.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_email1); ?>;
            name.readOnly = "readonly";
            phone.readOnly = "readonly";
            state.readOnly = "readonly";
            city.readOnly = "readonly";
            address.readOnly = "readonly";
            postcode.readOnly = "readonly";
            email.readOnly = "readonly";
            }
        else if (sel.value.trim() == "address_2") {
            name.value = fname.concat(" ").concat(lname);
            phone.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_phone2); ?>;
            state.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_state2); ?>;
            city.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_city2); ?>;
            address.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_address2); ?>;
            postcode.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_postcode2); ?>;
            email.value = <?php echo json_encode($my_user->user_email2); ?>;
            name.readOnly = "readonly";
            phone.readOnly = "readonly";
            state.readOnly = "readonly";
            city.readOnly = "readonly";
            address.readOnly = "readonly";
            postcode.readOnly = "readonly";
            email.readOnly = "readonly";
            }
        else {
            name.value = "";
            phone.value = "";
            state.value = "";
            city.value = "";
            address.value = "";
            postcode.value = "";
            email.value = "";
            name.readOnly = false;
            phone.readOnly = false;
            state.readOnly = false;
            city.readOnly = false;
            address.readOnly = false;
            postcode.readOnly = false;
            email.readOnly = false;
            }
            famil.value = lname;//name.value;
        
    }
</script>

But after pressing the "order register" button, the following error notices are displayed:

you must enter billing last name
you must enter billing country
you must enter billing state
you must enter billing city

The strange point is, just these 4 items are ignored, and the other parameters are ok.
